# Django - How do you create several model instances at the same time because they are connected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a user profile and the user profile has a location (address). I need to create the profile first and location second, and then match the profile and the location using a third model called ProfileLocation. I want to do this using one api call, because all the data comes from one form and the location depends on the profile.

There is a location model that has OneToOne fields for Country, State and City. The countries, states and cities will have the database tables populated before the time. There is an extra model called ProfileLocation that links the profile to the location. So I have to create all of them at once and struggling with what the best way to do it is. Also what type of DRF view do I use for the endpoint? I need to understand the logic please and I cannot find an example on the net.

Do I need to create a custom function based view and run the data through the existing serializers? In that case how can I bundle the incoming data for each specific serializer?

This is all very new to me

Locations model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dial_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "country"
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"
        db_table = "countries"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was created", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was updated", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "state"
        verbose_name_plural = "states"
        db_table = "states"
        unique_together = ["country", "name"]
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    state = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was created", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was updated", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "city"
        verbose_name_plural = "cities"
        db_table = "cities"
        unique_together = ["country", "state", "name"]
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    additional = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="countries")
    state = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="states")
    city = models.OneToOneField(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cities")
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "location"
        verbose_name_plural = "locations"
        db_table = "locations"
        ordering = ["zip"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug
```

This is my Location models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dial_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "country"
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"
        db_table = "countries"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was created", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was updated", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "state"
        verbose_name_plural = "states"
        db_table = "states"
        unique_together = ["country", "name"]
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    state = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was created", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("date post was updated", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "city"
        verbose_name_plural = "cities"
        db_table = "cities"
        unique_together = ["country", "state", "name"]
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"])
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    additional = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="countries")
    state = models.OneToOneField(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="states")
    city = models.OneToOneField(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cities")
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "location"
        verbose_name_plural = "locations"
        db_table = "locations"
        ordering = ["zip"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug
```

Here are the Location serializers which are ordinary modelserializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from profiles.models import ProfileLocation

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "country_code",
            "dial_code",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "country",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "country",
            "state",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = [
            "name",
            "street",
            "additional",
            "zip",
            "city",
            "phone",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]        

class ProfileLocationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileLocation
        fields =[
            "location"
            "profile"
        ]
```

and the profile serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from locations.serializers import ProfileLocationSerializer

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = ProfileLocationSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "background",
            "photo",
            "first_name",
            "middle_name",
            "last_name",
            "birthdate",
            "gender",
            "bio",
            "languages",
            "is_verified",
            "verification",
            "location",
            "website",
            "user",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return new_profile
```

This view creates the profile without any problems but excludes the location obviously.

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

your procedure is perfect, just need to override the create method of the serializer

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        # for better understand print or log the validated_data
        location_data = validated_data.pop('location') # all location data will be poped from the validated data as a dict
        # create a location object
        location_obj = Location.objects.create(**location_data)
        location_obj.save()
        # then add the location object in profile obj
        new_profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data, location=location_ojb)
        new_profile.save()
        return new_profile
```

please go through the [official doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: Thanks but the problem is location is made up of different fields. One for street, one for country etc. And the data coming in is filtered by the serializer and I only get the data for the profile. I need a way to get all the data, validate it and then have location data separate and profile data separate so i can save it to the models. This is where my problem lies